# How do I get the currenct value of a property?

Tags: frp, bacon.js

First entry in the [FAQ](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/wiki/FAQ)...

> There is no getLatestValue method available and will not be either.
>
> You get the value by subscribing to the stream/property (using
> onValue) and handling the values in your callback

What if I'm not ready for the value at the time that it arrives? Doesn't this mean I have to store a copy of it?

If you have to subscribe to a property to get its value, what is the point of properties? Why not only use streams?

My situation is that when a user presses a button, some config is updated. Else where in my code I need to read the latest config values. But this is not going to be at the same time that its changed.

Comment: Just use a combinator for your button click stream and the config property.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I have the config updating fine from a button click. Its using the value later on that I'm stuck on.

Comment: And where in your code do you need to use that config?

Comment: After an AJAX callback. During the callback the submit button is not enabled and has different text on it. When the request completes I need to switch the text back to what the current config says.

Comment: Sounds like you need another property telling you when the ajax request is active, and combine that with config. Or a stream of "ajax request complete" events to snapshot the "current" config values, if you need that.

Comment: I see. When the request returns it will pop out the response and I mix this event with the current config value.

Comment: The trouble with combining is now it calls the onValue at the end of the form submit when only the config changes. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`property.toEventStream()`](https://baconjs.github.io/api.html#property-toeventstream) to create an `EventStream` based on the Property where the stream contains also an event for the current value of the Property at the time this method was called.

Example:

```
// Config property created somewhere
var config = someStream.toProperty();

// Your behaviour depends on config
config.toEventStream().onValue(function(conf) {
    // React to config changes here
    // conf will be the "current" value on first call
});
```

As mentioned in comments, [combining streams and properties](https://baconjs.github.io/api.html#combining-multiple-streams-and-properties) might be more appropriate solution depending on what you are actually trying to do.